# Android drawing app. Draw, Save, Edit

Tags: android, drawing

I am new to Android and trying to develop an app that allow user to draw, save them which later on is able to reopen to edit and save back into the storage.

I have got the solution of drawing and saving part. However I am stuck with no idea how I can enable user to reopen the file for edit.

Will be grateful if someone could shed some light and provide me with clues or example how can this be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on how you draw and save the image. If you are saving it in a bitmap (png or jpeg) load it again and do other drawing operations with [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). You can do the drawings using a [SufaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)